# Testing routes in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What do I have to do so that this will work in the console (assuming `song` is defined, obviously):

```
edit_song(:id => song.id)
```

Comment: You can use `rake routes` to see a list of them, although it won't be able to throw objects into them.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have access to an `app` object which you can use to test routes on.

```
>> app.root_url
=> "http://www.example.com/"
>> app.root_path
=> "/"
```

Comment: @MichieldeMare Really? It works for me in Rails 3.0.7. Does it no longer work in Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 16):

The following imports named helpers for me in 3.2.8:

```
> include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> script/console
song = Song.first
edit_song_path(:id=>song.id)
```

assumes (routes.rb)

```
   map.resources :songs
```