# NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I would like to know if when using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is possible to have access to the variable `app`?

As an example, when I try to access the `root_path` I get the following error:

```
[14] pry(main)> app.root_path
NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for main:Object
```

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397644/testing-routes-in-the-console#comment19535097_1397660) said that "It does now work with pry and 3.2.9". I am using rails 3.2.12, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have `gem 'pry'` in my GemFile group development and in `config/environments/development.rb` the following

```
  # Use Pry instead of IRB
  silence_warnings do
    begin
      require 'pry'
      IRB = Pry
    rescue LoadError
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works

```
➜  MyApp git:(master) rc
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
[1] pry(main)> app.root_path
=> "/"
```

I use `pry-rails` in favor of your overriding of `IRB` in an initializer.

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails

Answer (score 0):

Though this is solved, if you don't want to or can't use the 'pry-rails' gem for some reason you can also add the following into your .pryrc file:

```
if defined?(Rails) && Rails.env
  extend Rails::ConsoleMethods
end
```

You can read more in the [pry wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry#wiki-with_gemfile)